Question regarding differentiating an integral with respect to its limits.
While solving a mechanics problem i came up with the following integral for computing the total torque,
$$\tau = \int_{x_0}^{\infty} \rho(x)(x-(x_0 + l))g\hspace{1mm}dx$$
I need to set the derivative of this with respect to $x_0$ to be 0, how would i do that, the variable with respect to which i am differentiating is in the limit as well as in the integrand.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Use this.
